# C++ socket

Tags: сокет, c++

Имеется кривой класс для работы с сокетами...

Имеется 2 вопроса:

1) При получение ответам, порт остается "забинденым" какое то время, как от этого избавится?

2) При получение адреса на который пришел запрос он будет = 0.0.0.0, как можно получить локальный и внешний адрес?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string>
use namespace std;

class a_socket {
   public:
    void init();
    void listen_port();
    string GetLastAddr();
    string GetServerAddr();
    string GetLastMessage() {  string mess_str(buffer); return mess_str; }
   private:
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, n;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
};

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

void a_socket::init()
{
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0)
      error("ERROR opening socket");

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 3131;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
         error("ERROR on binding");
}

string a_socket::GetLastAddr() {
   char ip[200];
   strcpy(ip, inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));
   string ipstr(ip);
   return ipstr;
}

string a_socket::GetServerAddr() {
   char ip[200];
   strcpy(ip, inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr));
   string ipstr(ip);
   return ipstr;
}

void a_socket::listen_port() {
    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

    if (newsockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR on accept");

    bzero(buffer,256);

    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);

    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
        printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);

    n = write(newsockfd,"OK", 2);

    if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR writing to socket");

    close(newsockfd); 
    close(sockfd);
}
```

Comment: Что бы можно было быстро перебиндиваться на тот же порт/адрес, используется такой вызов

    int option = 1;
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT | SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&option, sizeof option)

Но обычно код пишут так, что бы не открывать серверный сокет на каждый чих. Открыл и ждешь коннектов.

Comment: Может есть уже какие то готовые решения для работы с сокетами?

Comment: Какую задачу Вы пытаетесь решить? `listen/bind/socket/read` - это и есть готовые решения для данной задачи.

Comment: Что то типа не большого сервера, с веб-морды шлются команды, сервер принимает и обрабатывает их.

Comment: Постейший готовый сервер это inetd/xinetd (или даже netcat). 

Может именно этого Вам и достаточно?

Comment: Нет, сокеты, а именно команды должны для удаленного управления не большой программой.

Comment: посмотрите, как это все сделано у обычного irc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал обратить внимание на библиотеку для работы с сетью [ASIO](http://think-async.com/)